# Cofactor matrix of a hermitian positive definite matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a Hermitian, positive definite matrix and let $\tilde{A}$ be its cofactor matrix, i.e.

$ \tilde{A}_{i,j} = (-1)^{i+j} \det A^{(i,j)}$,

where $A^{(i,j)}$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ by omitting its $i$-th row and its $j$-th column.

I have already succeeded in proving that $\tilde{A}$ is Hermitian. How can I show that $\tilde{A}$ is positive definite ?

I know that for Hermitian matrices positive definiteness is equivalent to the fact that all eigenvalues are strictly positive. Otherwise, I don't have an idea how to start.

Comment: Since $\operatorname{cof}(A)=\det(A)(A^{-1})^\top$, it suffices to prove that the inverse, transpose or scalar multiplication by a positive factor of a positive definite matrix remain positive definite (and that the determinant of a positive definite matrix is positive).

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to user1551, there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, $P \in U(n, \mathbb{C})$ and a diagonal matrix $D=diag(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ with $\lambda_i >0$, $i=1, \dots, n$, such that $A=P D P^{*}$.

Therefore, $A^{-1}=P D^{-1} P^{*}$, where $D^{-1} = diag(\lambda_1^{-1},\dots,\lambda_n^{-1})$.

Since

- the transpose of a unitary marix is unitary,
- similar matrices have the same eigenvalues and
- $\det(A)>0$,

we see now that the eigenvalues of $\tilde{A}= \det (A) (A^{-1})^{T} = \det (A) (P^{T})^{*} D^{-1} P^{T}$ are all positive.